# How to integrate yelp v3 search api in android

Tags: java, android, yelp

Currently I have used `yelp v2 search api` but this api will be deprecated after **On June 30, 2018, API v2 will be discontinued and v2 endpoints will no longer work** and now new version v3 is available and I could not find suitable example for it...

Please help me for integrate v3 search api in android.

> GET
>   https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=delis&latitude=37.786882&longitude=-122.399972

Any help would be appreciated... Thanks